# Call function with name different from filename

Tags: matlab

I would like to have multiple functions in one .m file. Is this doable?

I tested with a file `mytest.m` that contains two functions.

```
function mytest()
    disp('my test');
end

function tst()
    disp('my test 2');
end
```

From another file, I can call the `mytest` function, but if I try to call `tst`, I get an error message saying `tst` is undefined.

Comment: You cannot call [local functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) from an external function. A class of [static methods](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html) may be more appropriate.

Comment: This is possible when using [classes](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/153441-call-a-function-inside-a-script-from-another-script).